# Replace string in url php

Tags: php

On my site, I have 2 languages: `md` and `ru`.

Default lang is: `md`.

When my user goes on site, http://site.ru/news/new-news-article, he shows content on language `md`. But if he goes to http://site.ru/ru/news/new-news-article, he is shown content on lang `ru` and if he go on http://site.ru/md/news/new-news-article, he is shown content on `md`.

I have 3 situations.

I need when user is located on language `md` with prefix `/md/` and without, change url on ru.

My code:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="https://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?><?=str_replace('/md/', '/ru/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>">
```

But this working only with prefix `/md/`, if user without prefix on url, this is not working.

Comment: Just initiate a session with lang and get that in a variable and print that in your href tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a proper way to handle languages, but following code should work. It cannot replace the `'/md/'` part if it's missing in the string, so you can test if present or not

```
<?=(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 4) === '/md/' ? str_replace('/md/', '/ru/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) : '/ru' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>
```

**NOTE**: there are different ways to have a better URL language system. It shouldn't really rely on the request URI to know what is the current page and what should be the alternate. In all cases, you should set a variable to know what is current user preferred language if it differs from his browser settings..